# Ubuntu 12.04 Freezes w/ Ethernet Unplugged + Wireless Drops (Acer Aspire 5516)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, acer, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Ubuntu 12.04-12.10 32/64 freezes or won't boot if the Ethernet cable is unplugged and will not hold a wireless connection.

Here is my scenario...

Laptop: Acer Aspire 5516
Wireless card: Broadcom BCM4312

**Ubuntu 12.04 32/64 Issues**

1. Unity 3d **won't** load without the Ethernet cable plugged in. If
   I let it load with Ethernet plugged in, it will freeze once I
   disconnect the cable.
2. Unity 2d **will** load without the Ethernet
   cable plugged.
3. In Unity 2d, wireless cannot hold a connection. I can
   connect to a Wireless network, but when I try to use it (i.e. open a
   browser), it disconnects. I can reconnect by disabling wireless
   (uncheck Enable Wireless), re-enable wireless, and reconnect. But,
   it will disconnect again once I start using it.

**Ubuntu 12.10 Issues**

1. Since 12.10 only gives me the option to load 3d (I assume), I experience the same thing as the first issue in 12.04.

**Attempted Solutions**

1. Enable networking/LAN in BIOS
2. Set LAN first in boot priority in BIOS
   Remove STA wireless driver (bcmwl-kernel-source) and install b43 low power driver (firmware-b43-lpphy-installer).
3. Remove default Network Manager and install Wicd.

So far, I have had no luck with fixing this issue.

Does anyone have any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Only workaround I have found so far is to boot into recovery mode, then resume.  It seems to work, though I have no idea why.

Comment: This does not provide a sufficient answer to the question. Try to add more information, and / or examples.